# A question on $\mathcal{L}_{1}$-spaces

Tags: banach-spaces

It is known that a Banach space $X$ is an $\mathcal{L}_{1}$-space if and only if $X^{*}$ is an $\mathcal{L}_{\infty}$-space. I want to know more about this result.

Question 1. If a Banach space $X$ is an $\mathcal{L}_{1,\lambda}$-space, it follows from the above result that $X^{*}$ is an $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\mu}$-space. I want to know what is the constant $\mu$?

Similarly,

Question 2. If a Banach space $X^{*}$ is an $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\lambda}$-space, it follows from the above result that $X$ is an $\mathcal{L}_{1,\mu}$-space. I want to know what is the constant $\mu$?

Is there any paper about my questions?

Thank you!